# How do I tell request getparameter to treat null value as 0?

Tags: java, spring-boot, crud

So I am currently doing a crud in spring boot and I am stuck at this place where i want to treat null id as 0, I have tried below version and it returns

```
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

   @ResponseBody
    public String checkMobileEmail(HttpServletRequest req, Model model) {
        String mobile = req.getParameter("mobile");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        Long id = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("id"));
        if (req.getParameter("id").equals("")) {
            id  = 0L;
        } 
        System.err.println("id : " + id + " mobile : " + mobile + " email: " + email);
        return service.findByEmailAndMobile(email,mobile,id);
    }
```

Comment: You can't do this before the if condition: `Long id = Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("id"));`.

Comment: Have you tried doing it like this:   ( req.getParameter("id") == null )

Comment: can you explain, why I can't do that?

Comment: I have yes @don, same results

Comment: someone just answered. I meant the same idea as the person who answered. Please try it out and check if it works.

Comment: yes @don, I checked it and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must avoid `Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("id"));` before the if condition as follows:

```java
@ResponseBody
public String checkMobileEmail(HttpServletRequest req, Model model) {
   String mobile = req.getParameter("mobile");
   String email = req.getParameter("email");
   String idParameter = req.getParameter("id");
   Long id = 0L;
   if (idParameter != null && !idParameter.equals("")) {
       id = Long.parseLong(idParameter);
   } 
   System.err.println("id : " + id + " mobile : " + mobile + " email: " + email);
   return service.findByEmailAndMobile(email,mobile,id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `id` is empty or `null` before calling `Long.parseLong` or it throws an exception.

```
Long id;
if (StringUtils.hasText(req.getParameter("id")) {
    Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("id"));
} else {
    id  = 0L;
}
```

You will still end up with an exception if the parameter is neither empty/null or a number. I would recommend to catch the exception and handle it appropriately.

```
try {
    Long.parseLong(req.getParameter("id"))
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    // log.warn(e) 
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```